# Can't update attribute in validate method - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Not really comfortable with active record yet

I wonder if it's possible to update an model attribute from another one like this:

```
validate :check_if_exist?

def check_if_exist?
    events = Event.where(kind: kind, starts_at: starts_at..ends_at).or(Event.where(kind: kind, ends_at: starts_at..ends_at))
    unless events.count == 0
        events[0].update_attribute(:starts_at, starts_at)
        events[0].update_attribute(:ends_at, ends_at)
        errors.add(:base, "Event ID##{events[0].id} updated")
        return false
    end
end
```

not sure at all i'm on the good way but I can't found any result when i'm looking for update a model instead of create like this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be updating the model in your validation. Assuming this is on the Event model, this is probably what you want.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :flash_notice
  before_create :terminate_existing

  def terminate_existing
    existing = Event.find_by(kind: kind, starts_at: starts_at..ends_at).or(find_by.where(kind: kind, ends_at: starts_at..ends_at))
    existing.update(starts_at: starts_at, ends_at: ends_at)
    flash_notice = "Event ID# #{existing.id} updated"
  end
end
```

#### EventsController

```
after_action :flash_notice, only: :create

def flash_notice
  unless @event.flash_notice.blank?
    flash[:notice] = @event.flash_notice
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`first_or_initialize`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize)

```
event = Event.where(kind: kind, starts_at: starts_at..ends_at).or(Event.where(kind: kind, ends_at: starts_at..ends_at)).first_or_initialize
event.update(starts_at: starts_at, ends_at: ends_at)
```